# Product space of Circle and interval is homeomorphic to annulus

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

Given a circle $C = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x^2+y^2=r^2\}$ and a closed interval $I=[a,b],\ 0\le a\le b$, the product topology on the product space $(C\times I, \mathcal{O}_{C\times I})$ shall be considered.

The annulus is defined by the set $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon a\le x^2+y^2\le b\}$.

I want to find a homeomorphism $f\colon (C\times I, \mathcal{O}_{C\times I})\rightarrow (A,\mathcal{O}_A)$.

As I have no experience in topology, I am unsure if my reasoning is correct.

Define $$ f((x,y),t) = (\frac{xr}{\sqrt{t}},\frac{yr}{\sqrt{t}}) $$

Then for $(u,v) = f((x,y),t)$ it holds that $$u^2+v^2=r^2\Leftrightarrow \frac{x^2r^2}{t}+ \frac{y^2r^2}{t}=r^2\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=t \Leftrightarrow a\le x^2+y^2 \le b $$

It must follow that $f(C\times I)=A$. As I can find an inverse by equivalence transformations we have a bijective map. Finally, since the map and its inverse is continuous in every component, it follows that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**EDIT**: Ok I think what I wrote was nonsense. Here is my proposed fix:

Define $$f((x,y),t)=(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r}, \frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r})$$

$f$ *is surjective*: For every point $(u,v)\in A$ we have that
$$a\le u^2+v^2\le b$$ This means there must exist a $t\in[a,b]$ such that
$$ u^2+v^2=t$$ From this it follows that
$$\frac{x^2t}{r^2}+\frac{y^2t}{r^2}=t \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=r$$ meaning we can find a preimage on $C\times I$.

$f$ *is injective*: From $$\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r}=\frac{x'\sqrt{t'}}{r}$$ and analogue for $y$ and $y'$ it follows that
$$\frac{x^2t}{r^2} +\frac{y^2t}{r^2}=\frac{x'^2t'}{r^2}+\frac{y'^2t'}{r^2}$$
and using $x^2+y^2=r^2$ therefore $t=t'$. This implies $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.

That $f$ is a topological map is not hard to see, since every component is a composition of continuous maps and likewise for the inverse.

Comment: What is the definition of $K$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Fixed the typo.

Comment: Overall it makes sense. You'll really improve what you did by: (1) saying precisely what $f$ definition set is, (2) explaining how do you prove that $f$ is bijective beyond aligning equations and (3) looking carefully at edge cases, in particular what if $a=b=0$. Last thing, you don't really fixed the typo. You still have $A$ and $K$ in the question.

Comment: Usually an annulus is specified by $a^2 \le x^2 + y^2 \le b^2$ - similarly as a circle. This is no essential difference, but it would simplify the formula for $f$. Instead of $\sqrt t$ we could write $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct idea, but I think your arguments are not adequate. [Edited: After your edit they are adequate, but I leave my answer as it is]. Here is a suggestion:

Define
$$f : C \times I \to \mathbb R^2, f((x,y),t) = \left(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r},\frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r} \right) .$$
This is clearly a continuous map. For $(x,y) \in C$ and $t \ge 0$ we have
$$\left(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r},\frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r} \right)  \in A \Leftrightarrow a \le \frac{x^2t}{r^2}+ \frac{y^2t}{r^2} = t \le b .$$
This shows that $f(C \times I) \subset A$. Next define
$$g : A \to \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R,g(u,v) = \left(\frac{ur}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}},\frac{vr}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}},u^2 + v^2 \right) .$$
This is a continuous map such that $(\frac{ur}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}},\frac{vr}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}) \in C$ and $u^2 + v^2 \in I$. Thus $g(A) \subset C \times I$. But for $(u,v) = f((x,y),t)  =\left(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r},\frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r} \right)$ we have $u^2 + v^2 = t$, thus
$$g(f((x,y),t)) = g\left(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r},\frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r} \right) = \left(\frac{x\sqrt{t}}{r}r/\sqrt{t},\frac{y\sqrt{t}}{r}r/\sqrt{t},t \right) = ((x,y), t) $$
and
$$f(g(u,v)) = f \left(\frac{ur}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}},\frac{vr}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}},u^2 + v^2 \right) = \left(\frac{ur}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}/r,\frac{vr}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}/r\right) = (u,v) .$$
This shows that $f$ and $g$ are inverse to each other.

Comment: I like this proof more than mine, you even give an inverse! How would you argue that the maps are continuous?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta The continuity of $f$ and $g$ can be directly proved by $\epsilon$-$\delta$-arguments. However, it also follows from the fact that addition, multiplication and forming quotients are continuous functions of two variables and that taking the square root is continuous. $f$ and $g$ are obtained by combining these for each coordinate function $f_i$, $g_j$.